# Place parentheses around a cross-reference for Figure

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, labels

I need to place my figure references between parenthesis for my Thesis. I've tried package `\hyperref` but it doesn't solve my problem.

If I try:

> `\autoref{'fig:label'}` I get something like
>
> > Figure (1);

However I need to get:

> **(Figure 1)**

Is there any way I can do that?

Here is my MWE:

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % This will give us the hyperlinks

\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and if you use any packages that modify the appearance of counter variables such as the `figure` counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `cleveref`, better than `autoref`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{figure}{#2(\figurename~#1)#3}

\begin{document}

In~\cref{foo} we see something.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\rule{3cm}{0pt}}

\caption{Something\label{foo}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want that the parentheses are part of the link, use

```
\crefformat{figure}{(#2\figurename~#1#3)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It has worked flawlessly!

Comment: @raulindo I'm not sure what you mean with the two comments.