# Cross-referencing to "fake" sub-pictures

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref

I'm currently writing an assignment report using `Latex` and I'm having some trouble when cross-referencing to "fake" sub-pictures.

> When I say fake it's because I'm importing a **single picture** drawn in Inkscape merging 4 different sub-figures like this [image]

I want to be able when I pass `\cref{fig:model}` I can reference to (Figure 1A) or (Figure 1B)

Here is my MWE:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{figure}{#2(\figurename~#1)#3}
 
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{report}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=10cm,width=16cm]{imagens/model.png}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:model}
\end{figure}


\bibliography{ref}{}
\bibliographystyle{geo-apalike}

\end{document}
```

I'm using a different format in `cref` as explained in here: [Place parentheses around a cross-reference for Figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549775/place-parentheses-around-a-cross-reference-for-figure)

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This draws on [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552811/4427), but also sets the anchors (approximately) at the right points: if you click on the links, you get moved to the proper subfigure.

The idea is to produce four empty `subfigure` environments that take the same space as the subfigures (the “approximate” refers to the small gap between the images, but it should not be a big concern). After these empty environments, the image is printed, but taking no vertical space, so it will exactly cover the previous space.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{figure}{#2(\figurename~#1)#3}
\newsavebox{\fourfigurebox}

\begin{document}

\cref{four:a},
\cref{four:b},
\cref{four:c},
\cref{four:d},
\cref{four}.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\sbox\fourfigurebox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fourimages}}% change with your own image

\begin{subfigure}[t][0.5\ht\fourfigurebox]{0.5\textwidth}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{four:a}
\end{subfigure}%<---- Don't forget
\begin{subfigure}[t][0.5\ht\fourfigurebox]{0.5\textwidth}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{four:b}
\end{subfigure}\par\nointerlineskip
\begin{subfigure}[t][0.5\ht\fourfigurebox]{0.5\textwidth}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{four:c}
\end{subfigure}%<---- Don't forget
\begin{subfigure}[t][0.5\ht\fourfigurebox]{0.5\textwidth}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{four:d}
\end{subfigure}\par\nointerlineskip
\smash{\usebox{\fourfigurebox}}

\caption{These are four images}\label{four}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg! Your solution was very clean and helped me a lot!

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you could insert a dummy `subfigure` environment, containing no graphs but just four `\refstepcounter` and `\label` directives, inside the `figure` environment to create four implicit (but invisible) subfigures.

That said, I can see nothing wrong in just writing "As shown in Panels A and B of \cref{fig:model}, ..."

[image]

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt, demo]{report} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}} % OP wants uppercase letters

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefformat{figure}{#2(\figurename~#1)#3}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth} % this 'subfigure' env. has no visible content
    \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:model:a}
    \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:model:b}
    \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:model:c}
    \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig:model:d}
\end{subfigure}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imagens/model.png}
\caption{A figure with four implicit subfigures}
\label{fig:model}
\end{figure}

As shown in \cref{fig:model:a} and \cref{fig:model:b}, \dots

As shown in Panels A and B of \cref{fig:model}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. It worked just fine!!